# Unable to access graphics settings

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, lxqt

On my computer (literally the motherboard ripped out of a laptop), the computer is telling the OS that the original laptop screen is still attached. So, now I am **unable to access the task bar**.
btw my window manager is **LXQT**. also my legit monitor is a cheap projector that is quite blurry.

I would like the **phantom display disabled** and would like to be able to launch retro-arch.

Comment: LXQt is actually WM agnostic and is a desktop, not a window manager.  Lubuntu uses LXQt but uses `openbox` to perform the WM functions (ie. maximize, minimize, re-size etc) where as Debian (with LXQt) uses `xfwm4` to perform that funciton.  Details in your question are wrong and you've not said what WM you're using (given you appear not to be using Lubuntu).

Comment: FYI:   As I don't know your stack, I can only be vague.. I've QA-tested & worked with Lubuntu on dead display laptops, and the easiest fix was using the Fn-Display keys which toggled internal/external/mirror/internal+external/... display.  If you're using the laptop keyboard (but external) then I'd hope a modern keyboard with Fn would still perform those functions (media key type extra functions on laptops, brightness up/down etc). Some models allowed disabling via BIOS/uEFI settings, some remembered the last setting you used on clean shutdown (many didn't!)